# Moments in Java OpenCV 3.0

Tags: java, opencv

According to [old documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/imgproc/Moments.html#Moments()), there is
`org.opencv.imgproc.Moments`
but I am not able to load it for OpenCV 3.0.

Was this functionality moved?

Comment: This issue is still not resolved.. https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/5017

Answer (score 0):

yes, it seems to be gone.

maybe make an [issue](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/issues) ?

Comment: Ok, Thanks! Will add an issue.